When a computer process hangs, what verb means, "The process became unstuck?"
I'm trying to report an issue regarding a program that inconsistently hangs. When this occurs, there are certain actions I can take to "unfreeze" it or "unhang" it. What's the appropriate verb to use for this action?
Here are some example sentences:

When it hangs, doing x <???> it.
I've tried many things, but when this happens, the only thing that <???> it is restarting my computer.
If I wait for an hour, the process <???> with an error. If I restart the process, it still hangs.


Why are you looking for another word when unfreeze could work? I'm no computer pro, so I could be inexact.

fixes........

I've also seen "unwedge", but I don't think it's inherently preferable to "unfreeze".

@TinfoilHat I like that but it doesn't work for #3. Maybe there's something different about that sentence?

@user405662 I think that works well. It's a no-brainer to go from "freeze" to "unfreeze," but I thought there might be a different word when you are starting from "hang." If not, I will accept that as an answer.

What is sentence (3) intended to mean? I assume it means "The program freezes and then, after an hour, exits with an error"?

@alphabet That is correct

#1 :  "doing x brings it back to operation". #2 : fixes.  # 3 : exits (@alphabet), terminates, ends.

#3 is different because the verb is intransitive.

In a computing context, the following are possible: continues, resumes, wakes, "is activated". You can validate my suggestion by searching for diagrams such as "computing process state transitions"

Unfreeze is a good choice.
Merriam-Webster has page for that verb which doesn't specify what types of freezing "unfreeze" applies to. But it includes in "Examples of freeze in a Sentence" (this is the examples curated by M-W, not the random ones from the internet) the example

He helped me to unfreeze my computer.

It's not in many dictionaries with this explicit sense, but many definitions are vague. The OED's entry on "unfreeze" was last updated in 1989, so it probably isn't up to date. But Wiktionary is newer and gives under unfreeze:


(transitive, computing) To release from a previously locked or frozen state.


Examples in print (the first two are transitive, the third intransitive):

ransomware, which freezes the computer and demands that a ransom be paid to unfreeze the computer (Using Technology to Enhance Clinical Supervision, ed Edina Renfro-Michel and Tony Rousmaniere, Wiley, 2016).


if the printer does not work it may cause the computer to freeze and the only way to unfreeze the computer is to switch it off, thus losing work (Design & Technology, Maggie Rogers, Nelson Thorne, 2002)


If you have a frozen computer that won't unfreeze or a computer that refuses to start properly... (My Windows 8.1 Computer for Seniors, Michael Miller, Pearson, 2013)

